# How to insert a table conditionally

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, insert

I have a table tbl1(col1, col2, col3, ..., coln), col1 and col2 together are the primary keys. I am trying to insert records from a temporary table #t to tbl1 using following query

```
insert into tbl1(col1, col2, col3, ..., colm)
select #t.col1, #t.col2, #t.col3, ..., #t.colm
from #t where col2 <> #t.col2
```

However, I got following error , The multi-part identifier "tblDailyBalanceHistory.BalanceDate" could not be bound. How do I fix my query?

Comment: It's sayng it can't figure out where that column in that table came from. That's as much help as we can give beacseu you haven't posted the actual sql, that causes the error.

Comment: my bad, the error message should be The multi-part identifier "tbl1.col2" could not be bound. But I don't think it would affect you understand my question. Someone gave me right answer.

Comment: They must be cleverer than me then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with your WHERE criteria.  You can't say col2 <> #t.col2 because col2 hasn't been defined.

Try something like this:

```
insert into tbl1(col1, col2, col3, ..., colm)
select #t.col1, #t.col2, #t.col3, ..., #t.colm
from #t 
   left join tbl1 on #t.col2 = tbl1.col2
where tbl1.col2 is null
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I just need to make a small adjustment, when I join two tables, I have to join on both col1 and col2 since they are combined primary key.